# Using Bitlocker + TPM protected HD, wish to permit boot alternate media (CD/USB)

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bitlocker

Our company is enabling Bitlocker entangled with TPM on our (Lenovo T430s) laptops with Win 7 Enterprise.

This setup will work well for 98% of the company staff without issue, but has created a problem for my team, as we occasionally use bootable DVD / thumbdrive distros for security tools.  We expect to use those distros self contained, so access to the Bitlocker protected HD / volumes is not required or expected.

At cold boot, we can still access the alternate boot menu via F12.  The alternate boot list explicitly lists the inserted media (for example, the specific vendor of the inserted USB stick.)

However, upon selection, while the media appears to be accesses, it does NOT boot, and returns directly to the menu after a moment. [In other words it behaves as media was not actual bootable.] The DVDs/thumbrdrives are known to be good, and in fact will boot an identical unprotected device.

Further, once this is attempted, the system detects a "boot change" a puts the device into the state requiring the Bitlocker numerical recovery password.

The team administering the rollout of Bitlocker is indifferent. They won't object to our team finding a solution, but they are not willing to research our "edge" use case.  (They had a hard time even understanding that booting from alternate media while keeping the HD locked was even a possibility.)

So how can I boot the USB? {Without triggering the Bitlocker enter recovery password state?}

Here are some of the things I've been asked elsewhere:

- I do have access to the BIOS generally (at least for now).
- Lenovo BIOS "Secure Boot" is NOT enabled.
- The internal HD is listed first in the boot order.
- I do have local admin privileges within Windows.
- At least at this time, I can suspend BitLocker. Doing so does not seem to assist in this issue though.
- Within Windows, I can view TPM settings through MMC panels.
- TO be clear, this is NOT Bitlocker + PIN protection. A TPM-only protector is added to the drive; so no pin or password is required. The second proctor is the numerical recovery password.
- We have explicitly test requiring a PIN to Bitlocker, which does not help in this endeavor.
- This is not UEFI booting
- I can provide (if needed) screenshots of every relevant BIOS screen.
- This is utilizing the most current BIOS update available.
- Removing the internal HD requires a screwdriver, so this is not considered a viable working option. A VM image within Windows is also not an option we want to persue.

I can add even more details if requested, but I'm trying not to overload the question initially.

Comment: Without access to the BIOS, you can't change the boot order, which means you standing in a creek without a boat or a paddle.  In other words not only are you stuck you have no path forward based on that fact alone.  Windows 7 does not support UEFI Secure Boot feature, so it being disabled, is a given.

Comment: @Ramhound:  Thanks for the fast reply, but I think you misread (see the bullets):  I do have access to the BIOS and the F12 alternate boot.   In fact, I am the one who moved the HDD to first boot item.  When (as originaly set)  the internal HDD was after the DVD/USB -- it would aotomatically tkae me to the prompt for the Bitlocker key.  I didn't know that Secure boot was incompatible with Win7 good to know.

Comment: Do all the protected laptops have only one logon? I'm asking because I have the impression that for multiple users, Bitlocker with TPM requires a PIN, but when booting from alternate media you do not use this one user account. You can easily test this.

Comment: @harrymc the laptop is part of a domain.  Any authorized user in the domain can log into the laptop.   (In fact I have multiple identities and can login with either, and my cubicle mate can do the same, even with BL enabled).  No pin required.

Comment: Pin not required, but may help (I'm not too sure about it, but something I read seems to give this hint).

Comment: Note: There is a [BIOS update](http://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t430s?tabName=Downloads&linkTrack=Mast:SubNav:Support:Drivers%20and%20Software|Drivers%20and%20Software&beta=false) available from April 2016. It might be interesting to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Has the laptop ever booted from a CD/USB Drive?

Comment: "The DVDs/thumbrdrives are known to be good, and in fact will boot an identical unprotected device." I think this means password encryption is not in place when it's unprotected, but password is necessary or already in place when protected. I'm wondering if you could rewrite your boot with a pre DOS command/batch call? If you could write a boot to accept a command then this command might be of some use: "manage-bde L: -unlock -recoverypassword xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx". I use something similar with my BitLocker where L is the drive letter. It's a batch I use.

Comment: You state that secure boot is disabled. Does the bios then also force you to set an OS mode? I had to choose between three options. UEFI OS or CSM OS or "UEFI and CMS OS". I remember that I was unable to boot to the USB if I did not specifically change it to cms only. For some reason the combo mode did not work as expected. Since you are running 7, cms is required. The question is: do you have this bios toggle and what is its current setting? I had the same trouble with AHCI mode toggle. Maybe it won't help you, but to be complete you could add the state of those toggles to your list.

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz...   Yes, before the recent reinstall, I wiped the device with my bootable DBAN CD.

Comment: @ejbytes    Basically I was trying to make it clear that I was using valid bootable media.   (I used the same DBAN cd to wipe the drive prior to the reinstall, and it still works on identical laptops that have not been reinstalled).   I can't (at least easily) rewrite the boot, its a delivered ISO (DBAN) that is Linux based.

Comment: @A71, I'll go back to that.   What I can tell you is that when Secure Boot is disabled, it disables several other settings on the page.  On a different boot page the settings are UEFI/Legacy Boot: BOTH.   UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority: Legacy First  .   CSM Support: YES,.

Comment: @harrymc:   Hmmm... now that I have  looked, this device has a BIOS that is multiple generations old.    This does make me want to install it to bring it current, but also makes me nervous (in that it is a corporate machine, and lord help me if I brick it.  I'm gong to have to think hard about this...

Comment: @harrymc:    Well, looks like a BIOS issue could well be this issue.  In one of the intermediate BIOS fixes is this nugget:    - (Fix) Fixed an issue where the system failed to boot from a USB device by
        configuration.

Comment: I have added an answer. Most BIOS updates I have done went well, but I was sure nervous when doing it.

Comment: @harrymc   Sorry to say, the BIOS update, despite the possibility of a fix based on the Release notes, did not correct the issue.   This is maddening! ;-(

Comment: AFAIK Bitlocker+TPM is OS-locked, and even booting from USB may require access to the hard disk. The PIN might give it that permission, so it's worthwhile testing. even as a theoretical test. I must remark that I don't understand why you people think that without the PIN your data is still secure - it's much more likely that a laptop will be stolen than just its hard disk.

Comment: @harrymc  Sorry, but as I expected, adding PIN does not help the situation.  The invocation for the PIN comes after you have already stareted running from the Windows "Support volume" or whatever the "extra" partion is.       At this point, I'm pretty convinced it is something very specific to Lenovo and this particular device.   I wish I had a completely different machine to test with to confirm this, but alas.

Comment: It can also always be a Microsoft gotcha. I don't have your environment, but what I gather should have happened is that the boot from USB should have been detected as a change in the boot order and so cause a prompt for the BitLocker recovery key. Did you try to put the USB as first in boot order?